# Как заполнить список случайными числами?

Tags: java, list, коллекции, список, библиотеки

Есть список:
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
Мне необходимо, чтобы он содержал 10 случайных чисел, как это сделать?

Comment: Запустить генератор случайных чисел десять раз.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
List<Integer> list = new Random().ints()
                                 .limit(10)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

P.S. 2019-й год на дворе, не используйте *сырые* типы.